# Why is the authentication_string different from the other one if the passwords are the same?

Tags: mysql, authentication, password

I've set the same passwords for the following accounts: `'root'@'%'`, `'root'@'127.0.0.1'`.
When I type `select user, host, authentication_string from mysql.user` I get different values for the `authentication_string`.
[image]

Is it because the other way of encryption is used for external accounts like `'%'`?

Comment: add plugin to the columns you want to show and look which plugin is used

Comment: Oh! That's the thing! For `'root'@'127.0.0.1' mysql_native_password` is used and for `'root'@'%'` it's `caching_sha2_password`. Looks like the last one is more secure.

Comment: yes but if you have programms that don't support it, you need the natove passwort

Comment: @nbk I'm not sure about that. For now I use MySQL only with my JIRA software.

Comment: as i stated in the first post of you, a migration is quite complicated and you must follow the steps of the linked mysql. Yopu can only cnnect with ipv6 usually i would say see the(also linked in then answer) and change the bind parameter in the mysql,cnf(ini ifle. But i honestly can't tell what your system looks like, because i don't think that you made a correct migration. So i would recommend, start from a backup and start over